# jQuery UI Autocomplete not working unless I call $.parseJSON in console

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've seen plenty of other questions about jQuery UI Autocomplete but none exactly like what's wrong with mine.

I'm using Rails 3.2 with the jquery-ui-rails plugin (which uses jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.9.2). The top of my `application.js` file contains all of my jQuery:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.core
//= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
```

I followed Railscast [#399](http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms?view=asciicast) to set this up but am finding that my autocomplete filtering doesn't actually work unless I go into the console, run $.getJSON on my source, then $.parseJSON on the $.getJSON responseText.

Without that I just a get a drop down of the available strings from the array returned by my server.

Here's my input in my HTML:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'location_name', nil, id: "all_location_search" %>
```

The CoffeeScript that calls autcomplete on that HTML:

```
$ ->
  # autocomplete location input
  $('#all_location_search').autocomplete
    source: "/autocompletions/locations"
```

In AutoCompletionsController#locations:

```
def locations
  render json: AutoComplete.locations_by(params[:location_name])
end
```

And in AutoComplete.rb:

```
def self.locations_by(term)
  current = Profile.pluck(:current_location).reject{|n| n.blank?}
  current.grep(/^#{term}/)
end
```

Now if I point my browser to `localhost:3000/autocompletions/locations` I see the following:

```
["Arlington, VA","Atlanta, GA","Boston, MA","Coral Springs, FL","Philadelphia, PA","Sterling, VA"]
```

But like I said unless I go into the console, run something like:

```
locations = $.getJSON("/autocompletions/locations")
locationJson = $.parseJSON(locations.responseText)
$('#all_location_search').autocomplete({source: locationJson});
```

I don't actually get a filter.

A few things to note:

- I'm calling `.autocomplete` on two inputs. I tried removing one to see if that did anything but it didn't
- I tried removing every JavaScript to see if another file was causing the issue but didn't find anything
- The HTML output when I load the page of the input where jQuery UI Autocomplete should be is the same as the HTML output I get when I enter both options below in Chrome's developer console.

`<input id="all_location_search" name="location_name" type="text" data-validate="true" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">`

#### Option 1

```
$('#all_location_search').autocomplete({source: "/autocompletions/locations"});
```

#### Option 2

```
locations = $.getJSON("/autocompletions/locations")
locationJson = $.parseJSON(locations.responseText)
$('#all_location_search').autocomplete({source: locationJson});
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous call. The fact that you're calling `locations.responseText` immediately instead of using a callback function is probably problematic. By the time you finish typing `$.parseJSON` the response has come back. When the code is actually executing, the response has not finished by the time the `$.parseJSON` line is executed.

Comment: Also instead of `search` for **Option 1** you want `source`. Could that be your issue?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typing error. I have it as source. I'll fix it now.

Comment: I think @AndrewWhitaker's first comment is spot on and is the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, but in that option I was just demonstrating how I got it to work manually. The code I'm using to call autocomplete in my actual js.coffee file - `$('#all_location_search').autocomplete({source: locationJson});` - isn't working.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was in my form's `text_field_tag` helper. I'll add it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. First of all, what hits the server with jQuery UI Autocomplete is a term param, so I had to match against that. So changing my controller method from:

```
def locations
  render json: AutoComplete.locations_by(params[:location_name])
end
```

To...

```
def locations
  render json: AutoComplete.locations_by(params[:term])
end
```

Fixes it. I'd seen this in other answers but don't think I typed with the case-sensitivity of my terms in mind. Just make sure you look for `params[:term]`.